# json schema - field is required based on another field value

Tags: jsonschema

I'm working on creating a JsonSchema(v4).
I'm trying to make one property required based off the value of another property from it's parent.

Parent

- User

  - subtype
  - address

Child

- Address

  - line1
  - line2
  - companyName (required if user subtype is company)

How could this be done?
I have something like this now...

```
{
 "User": {
  "title": "User",
  "type": "object",
  "id": "#User",
  "properties": {
     "subtype": {
      "type": "string"
     },
     "address": {
      "$ref": "Address"
     }
  }
 }


 "Address": {
  "title": "Address",
  "type": "object",
  "id": "#Address",
  "properties": {
     "line1": {
      "type": "string"
     },
     "line2": {
      "type": "string"
     },
     "companyName": {
      "type": "string"
     }
   },
   "required": ["line1", "line2"]
 }
}
```

Subtype is a arbitrary string, so a full list of the different subtypes is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your User schema.  Essentially it reads as: either "subtype" is not "company" or "address" requires "companyName".

```
"anyOf": [
  {
    "not": {
      "properties": {
        "subtype": { "enum": ["company"] }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "properties": {
      "address": {
        "required": ["companyName"]
      }
    }
  }
]
```